# FFMpeg Text Animation

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How to add text with animation on video in ffmpeg?
Now I am trying to add video management function on android app.
If you have a experiences on it, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I added the visible, marquee,several text lines animation on video in ffmpeg.
It works well.
Here is my code.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='First Line': fontcolor=red: fontsize=40: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=if(lt(t\,3)\,(-h+((3*h-200)*t/6))\,(h-200)/2):enable='between(t,2.9,50)',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='Second Line': fontcolor=yellow: fontsize=30: x=if(lt(t\,4)\,(-w+((3*w-tw)*t/8))\,(w-tw)/2): y=(h-100)/2:enable='between(t,3.5,50)',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='Third Line': fontcolor=blue: fontsize=50: x=if(lt(t\,5)\,(2*w-((3*w+tw)*t/10))\,(w-tw)/2): y=h/2:enable='between(t,4.5,50)',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf: text='Fourth Line': fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=if(lt(t\,6)\,(2*h-((3*h-100)*t/12))\,(h+100)/2):enable='between(t,5.5,50)'[out]" out.mp4
```

Here "input.mp4" is your input video file and it will output with the name "out.mp4"